# Select the range of values in the column based on the interval of values in the other column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
scale    year       value
-10      2017       1 252
-9       2017       1 011
-8       2017         921
-7       2017       1 161
-6       2017       1 331
-5       2017       1 133
-4       2017         899
-3       2017       1 063
-2       2017       1 320
-1       2017       1 201
 0       2017       1 212
 1       2017       1 543
 2       2017         656
 3       2017         443
 4       2017       1 398
 5       2017       1 776
...
```

I need to select the values in `value` column that correspond to the range of values in `scale` column, where `scale` between `0` and `-7`. In the example it will be the values  from `1 212` to `1 161`.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
df = df[df['scale'].between(-7,0)]
print (df)
    scale  year  value
3      -7  2017  1 161
4      -6  2017  1 331
5      -5  2017  1 133
6      -4  2017    899
7      -3  2017  1 063
8      -2  2017  1 320
9      -1  2017  1 201
10      0  2017  1 212
```

Answer (score 2):

we can also use `.query` method:

```
In [39]: df.query("-7 <= scale <= 0")
Out[39]:
    scale  year  value
3      -7  2017  1 161
4      -6  2017  1 331
5      -5  2017  1 133
6      -4  2017    899
7      -3  2017  1 063
8      -2  2017  1 320
9      -1  2017  1 201
10      0  2017  1 212
```